# Passing array of functions as argument to function

Tags: c

My C is a bit rusty. Suppose I have the following

```
char* (*funcs[n])(void);
```

How would I define or declare another function to take this array as parameter. I tried with

```
void func(char* (*p)(void));
```

But gcc complains.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The parameter has the same type as the array, except that you can omit the size:

```
void print(char* (*p[])(void)) { ... }
```

You can also use the fact that the array decays into a pointer and declare:

```
void print(char* (**p)(void)) { ... }
```

These function signatures are equivalent. In the function, call the function with either of these:

```
char *a = (*p)();
char *b = (p[0])();
```

These calls are equivalent, too.

But, as user694733 points out in the comments, everything is made easier by making a `typedef` for functions of a certain signature, say:

```
typedef char *(*Charpfunc)(void);
```

Then you can just use the familiar syntax for your arrays and function parameters:

```
char *hello(void) { return "hello"; }
char *howdy(void) { return "howdy"; }
char *goodbye(void) { return "goodbye"; }

typedef char *(*Charpfunc)(void);

void print(Charpfunc *p)
{
    while (*p) {
        puts((*p)());
        p++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    Charpfunc funcs[] = {
        hello, howdy, goodbye, NULL
    };

    print(funcs);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 But I would also recommend making type definition for the function pointer `typedef char* (*T)(void)`, so it could be written like normal arrays are: `T array[]`.