# Passing array of functions (with arguments) as argument to function

Tags: c

An extension question to [Passing array of functions as argument to function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28066510/passing-array-of-functions-as-argument-to-function#new-answer).

I would like to pass an array of functions (with their own arguments) as argument to another function.

Simply, instead of making them void, adding arguments to them.

Code borrowed from the mentioned question:

```
char *howdy(void) { return "howdy"; }
char *goodbye(void) { return "goodbye"; }

typedef char *(*Charpfunc)(void);

void print(Charpfunc *p)
{
    while (*p) {
        puts((*p)());
        p++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    Charpfunc funcs[] = {
        hello, howdy, goodbye, NULL
    };

    print(funcs);
    return 0;
}
```

I've tried the obvious solutions, but could not make it work.
Most common error was: typedef is initialized (use decltype instead) or converting from one type to another.

Comment: those argument can be added as another parameter of the main function, where the array is passed.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what the question is. Your code works in its current state (provided that you remove the `hello` function pointer from the array as that is undeclared). Would you like to pass arguments to the functions you're calling?

Comment: The code you show here is fine, what's the problem?? You need to show the code you're having problems with, not only the original code upon which _your_ code is based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what *"(with their own arguments)"* in your question is suppsed to mean exactly.

Are you looking for something like this?

```
#include <stdio.h>

char* howdy(int arg) { printf(">howdy: arg = %d\n", arg); return "howdy"; }
char* goodbye(int arg) { printf(">goodbye: arg = %d\n", arg);  return "goodbye"; }

typedef char* (*Charpfunc)(int arg);

void print(Charpfunc* p, int arg)
{
  while (*p) {
    puts((*p)(arg));
    p++;
  }
}

int main()
{
  Charpfunc funcs[] = {
      howdy, goodbye, NULL
  };

  print(funcs, 111);
  print(funcs, 222);
  return 0;
}
```

or maybe something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char* howdy(int arg) { printf(">howdy: arg = %d\n", arg); return "howdy"; }
char* goodbye(int arg) { printf(">goodbye: arg = %d\n", arg);  return "goodbye"; }

typedef char* (*Charpfunc)(int arg);

void print(Charpfunc* p, int *arg)
{
  while (*p) {
    puts((*p)(*arg));
    p++;
    arg++;
  }
}

int main()
{
  Charpfunc funcs[] = {
      howdy, goodbye, NULL
  };

  int arg111[] = { 1, 11 };
  int arg222[] = { 2, 22 };
  print(funcs, arg111);
  print(funcs, arg222);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks. I've come to this solution after writing this post too :-)